# Bootstrap Bootbox removing popup after clicking save button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

**HTML**

```
<a href="#modal-2" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Modal with animation</a>

<div id="modal-2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"  id="book" >Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**i have used floowing JS, but no result**

```
 $('#book').click(function(e) {
       $.ajax({
            url: base_url+"admin/login/",
            type: "get",
            data: {Name:name, Mobile:mobile},
            success: function( strData ){
                //$('.modal, .modal-backdrop').hide();
                $("#modal-2").modal('hide');

            },
            error: function(){
                $('#report').text('Sorry, Please try again').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
```

here i want to call a ajax function in callback after clicking save button.
then after on ajax success i want to close the bootbox popup

Comment: i'm unable close popup

Comment: I have no issues with closing your pop up when run your code in jsfiddle.  You have one issue where you add "hide" into your modal's class and that will prevent your modal from opening.  There is probably something else causing an issue.

Comment: can you post that fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6hK/  -- here you go

Comment: on ajax succes this $("#modal-2").modal('hide'); is not working

Comment: Well, I don't believe that is the issue, here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6hK/2/  -- should move on to the promise syntax -- ajax success, error, complete have been deprecated

Comment: i dont know for me it is not working

Comment: Does the Fiddle work for you?  There is probably something else causing an issue if the fiddle works for you because it is the code you have posted.

Comment: fiddle is working for me, but the same code is not working in my application

Comment: Make sure there isn't anything else preventing the close such as errors or if the code is under a document ready, etc.  I don't think there is anything wrong with the piece you have posted thus far.

Comment: this error is printing on console Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal' version.js:600
$.ajax.success version.js:600
c VM5145:3
p.fireWith VM5145:3
k VM5145:5
r  after clicking save button

Comment: It sounds like you have a duplicate library.  Check if you have anything duplicated. Ex: jquery, bootstrap.js and other js plugins

Comment: For Bootstrap dialogs not to close, you should return false in the callback functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use BootBox, you could do something like this:

```
bootbox.dialog({
        message: "Your Message Here - You can pass in an HTML string",
        title: "Your Title",
        onEscape: function () {
            bootbox.hideAll();
        },
        buttons: {
            danger: {
                label: "Cancel",
                className: "btn default",
                callback: function () {
                    bootbox.hideAll();
                }
            },
            success: {
                label: "Add",
                className: "btn blue",
                callback: function () {

        //Add functionality here

        // Then close the model using
        bootbox.hideAll();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it is still not waiting until ajax complete. It always closes windows after clicking button.

Answer (score 0):

inside ajax definition you should use parameter

```
async : false
```

It's possible that you will have to use custom buttons inside the body of the modal window, not these from bootbox